# PHP if else statement that opens up a modal if using a specific browser doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a modal appear on a user's screen if they are using Google Chrome.
I have like zero idea what I'm doing. I know that I am detecting the browser correctly, but I do not know how to open up the modal. The modal opens if I put the if/else statement into a comment, but that means it will open up in every browser.

```
<?php

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
$detectBrowser = strtolower($browser['browser']);

if ($detectBrowser == "chrome") {
header("Location: #BrowserWindow");
}

else { 
}

?>
```

In the body:

```
<div id="BrowserWindow" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

The modal is obviously just for a test. When I load it on Google Chrome, it says "This webpage has a redirect loop."

Comment: It seems that your modal window is in the same page as the testing of the browser name. So even if you redirect to 'modal window page' you stay at the same page -> keep testing which browser are you using and then redirect again. Try redirect to another page ( which does not test the browser) or use echo (for testing purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to redirect via header() to #BrowserWindow. Because you're not calling a path on a web server you're stuck in a redirect loop (because the header() function is looking for a resource on a server and you're trying to have it open an element on your page). More info on header(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Your best bet would be to script it out in Javascript and have it open the modal on detection. Here is a tutorial to get you started: http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The location header causes a redirect every time the page is loaded in chrome, even if the anchor already reflects #BrowserWindow. This is causing a redirect loop.

Unfortunately, the hash(#) part of the URL is never sent to the server, so you couldn't check this if you wanted to.

You're going to have to use javascript, which is a much better way to do this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
The header function is made to send http headers like 404 or redirect to a special page. You are trying to access the content of a page with header which is basically impossible.

PHP is a server-side language and can't interfere in your html once sent.

Instead try to write in your html the browser detected to open your modal in JS.

```
echo "var browser = ".$detectBrowser;
```

and then write JS

@+